# Jar file not displaying (closes too fast)

Tags: java, file, jar, cmd

Whenever I double click a .JAR file OR run it from the console (cmd) it appears briefly for a split second and then disappears.

I have written a very basic program, with a GUI, and I was hoping to see it displayed. 
How do I make the JAR file visible for myself?

Comment: Post code here. Run it through the command line see if you get any errors

Comment: Please dont post the whole code, first look at the errors :)

Comment: @Confiqure, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

try this it may help you :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Stackkkk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame =new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JLabel("Name"));
        JTextField textfield=new JTextField();
        textfield.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        frame.add(textfield);
        frame.show();
        //to stop the the program when jframe is closed 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

create a jar file

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is a check gry check box under the my answer the  < 0 > in the head of every answer so when some one give a right answer you click on the check box to accept there question as a right answer to help other too you see the zero there is button  UP and  Down     " < 0 > " click on the gry check button  or on the up to make zero a one that's how to vote for answer

Answer (score 0):

Run the .jar file from the command line, using:

```
java -jar path/to/your/File.jar
```

By doing this, the window won't close after the application finishes executing so you can see any errors.

Comment: Nothing happens....

Except it says the filename.jar at the top of the cmd window.....

Comment: @TonyNarloch Are you using an IDE such as Eclipse, IntelliJ or NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, I am. I created my program using NetBeans, compiled it successfully, have set the PATH enviroment variable properly, etc etc.

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1

Comment: @TonyNarloch Try using NetBeans Debugger to go through your programm step by step

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I type 

java -jar NumberAddition.jar  and it effectively opens and closes instantly even in the cmd. Please note, i am also running the cmd as an adminstrator

Comment: @TonyNarloch I wasn't talking about your build proccess, have you ever used the debugger? If not, watch some tutorials so you don't have to ask for help everytime something is wrong.

Comment: IF you don't know, the Debugger is a developement tool which helps you identifying errors and their causes.

Comment: Ok, Well Im sorry. Its just when I clicked on debug project, it gave me that information, i.e. "build successful".

Please don't patronise me. This is my very first time coding, ever.

Comment: @TonyNarloch I have no clue how NetBeans works, i rarely use it, i am an eclipseuser

Comment: @TonyNarloch No prob if that is your first time, but it is good if you learn how to handle your problems because you don't want to ask other people forever right :)

Comment: Well, it would seem that by clicking on "Debug File" has now meant the JAR file is working!

Thank you.

Comment: @TonyNarloch uh? ok? but just debugging a file doesnt mean it works, probably you made something wrong when you compiled and that is why it didn't work outside of netbeans